# Issue with archiving ios build ionic

Tags: ios, ionic3, archiving

I have an issue when trying to archive my ionic application.

```
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using cocopods. When I get this issue to build it for my iphone I am doing:

```
 > Product > Scheme > GoogleToolboxForMac
```

Then I build it. And finally I am going back to my app and build it.

However when I am doing this before archiving the issue keep continue...

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
Go to your ios project in command line then type :

```
pod install
```

Then retry and it is ok